# Adding an additional column to every matrix in a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, dictionary

I have a list of matrices that I am using the Map function to operate upon. Here is a simplified version of the list:

```
x = Map(function (i) matrix(sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3), 1 : 3)
```

What I want to do is add an additional column to each matrix in the list where each new column is an identifier (ie: an ID number for the table like 1, 2, etc) so that I could eventually join the matrices together. The actual data I'm working with is yearly so I need to label each row with the appropriate year it's from (ie: the table name).

So, my desired outcome after adding the additional column in this example would be:

```
> x[[1]]

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] <- new column
[1,]    1    8    2    1
[2,]    6    1    7    1
[3,]    5   10    5    1
[4,]    1    9    8    1
[5,]    7    4   10    1
```

Any guidance is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: like so? `lapply(1:length(x), function(id) cbind(x[[id]], id))`

Comment: @rawr, submit as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just channeling rawr's answer in the comments to my original question. rawr, if you ever want credit just submit your answer and I'll give you the all important check.

Solution:

```
x <- lapply(1:length(x), function(id) cbind(x[[id]], id))
```